# Метод submit у формы асинхронен?

Tags: javascript, form, submit

Столкнулся с проблемой (не ожидаемым поведением) в ФФ, когда определенный код выполнялся после `form.submit()`, хотя казалось, что этого не должно быть... При чем в Хроме все работало ожидаемо.
Набросал код-иммитацию:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('send')
form.addEventListener('submit', ()=>{
  console.log("Hi, from submit")
})
setTimeout(function() {
  form.submit();
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(123) 
   },0)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<form action="" id="send">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="">
   <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

По идее, `console.log(123)` мы не должны увидеть, однако видим. Получается, что `submit` асинхронен?

П.С.: в реальности ситуация была такова (выдержка из кода):

```
//отправка данных формы, после валидации
    form.submit()
//идет перебор элементов формы, в котором эти элементы дизейблятся
        elements.forEach(elm => {
            elm.readOnly = true
            elm.disabled = true
        })
```

В ФФ проблема возникла в том, что на сервер значения инпутов приходили пустыми. Проблема исчезла, когда была удалена строка `elm.disabled = true`. Это говорит  о том, что полям формы успевал применится атрибут `disabled` и, соответственно, значения не передавались на сервер.

Comment: проблема была только с ФФ?

Comment: @Grundy, да. В Хроме все ОК. Сафари - не проверял

Answer (score 2):

Страница существует, и js в ней выполняется, пока в браузер не придет первый байт ответа на сабмит.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос. И получается, что Ваш ответ не поясняет его... Страница-то существует, однако код, что ниже `submit()` успевает выполнится до отправки данных

Comment: @Дмытрык Зато он поясняет исходный вопрос ).

Comment: Согласен) А есть объяснение к дополнению?)